# Difference in performance between the following two implementations of binary search

Tags: algorithm, performance, binary-search, coding-efficiency

I came across these two implementations of binary search in the book "Competitive Programmer's Handbook" https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf.

### Method 1:

```
int a = 0, b = n-1; 

while (a <= b) { 
    int k = (a+b)/2; 
    if (array[k] == x) { 
        // x found at index k
    }
    if (array[k] > x) 
        b = k-1; 
    else
        a = k+1;
}
```

## Method 2:

```
int k = 0; 

for (int b = n/2; b >= 1; b /= 2){ 
    while (k+b < n && array[k+b] <= x) 
        k += b;
}
if (array[k] == x){ 
    // x found at index k
}
```

I guess *method 2* is not exactly binary search.
I understand that Both *method 1* and *method 2* have O(log n) complexity. Also the code for *method 2* is simpler and therefore might result in fewer bugs.

**My questions are:**

- Is there any improvement in performance when method-2 is used?
- Does method-2 have any other advantage?

Comment: Method 2 is not a working implementation of search. It makes no sense whatsoever to compare it to an implementation of search. You could just as well comare binary search and a no-op. A no-op is faster than binary search, OK, what's next?

Comment: Fewer code and "simpler" (I don't agree) doesn't mean fewer bugs. In my opinion the first implementation is easier to understand, I can immediately see what is going on, so I prefer this implementation.

Comment: method 2 works, and can almost be called binary search, but it's a lot trickier than it looks.

Comment: method 2 is definitely not simpler (and probably slower in practice), although it contains a neat idea that could have applications outside of binary search.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Method 2 _is_ a working implementation of search although there's plenty to dislike about it. I originally thought it was buggy, but it's actually correct. It doesn't quite do binary search -- it's more like binary/trinary search where the array is divided into halves if it's of even length, and divided into sections of length [n/2, n/2, 1] if it's of odd length.

Comment: If we knew that n is a power of two, then the while in method 2 could be converted into an if. IOW, method 2 will perform two many tests. But couldn't we seed b with an overestimate (half the next power of two > n)?

Comment: @PaulHankin: it's the opposite. Method 1 uses two tests in a row, which yield three possible outcomes. This one is ternary. Method 2 is pure binary.

Comment: @aka.nice: why do yo think that method 2 will do too many tests ?

Comment: For method 1, wouldn't most modern compilers fuse the two comparisons into one? If not, it seems you could cut the number of comparisons by roughly a quarter on average by swapping the two compares (so that it compares for _greater_ before _equal_).

Comment: @YvesDaoust when n is odd, array indices a[k+b] and a[k+2b] are tested (in the worst case). That `while` really needs to be a `while` and can't be an `if`. That's why I think the code's deceptive.

Comment: @PaulHankin: why would a[k+2b] be tested ??

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: that's possible. Need to check the assembly code. Notice that in Method 2, the test can be implemented by a conditional assignment. In Method 1, this is less clear.

Comment: @PaulHankin: why would a[k+2b] be tested ?? Note that the even/odd parity issue exists in both methods, the computations are in fact identical: (a + b) / 2 = a + (b - a) / 2 = a + n / 2.

Comment: On second thoughts, I didn't read the code of Method 2 carefully, sorry guys. There should not be an inner while loop. OP, if you un-accept my answer, I will delete it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust method 2 is like setting the index 1 bit at a time. We need a single if per bit. Statistically, one loop out of two, the while is going to test what we already tested in previous loop. i.e. `array[k+b]<x` then `array[(k+b)+b]<x`. But in previous loop we already tested `array[k+2*b]<x`. The while here is because we did not seed `b=larger_power_of_two(n)/2`.

Comment: Sorry I misread the code, it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such short code and so few differences, it is impossible to do any prediction. The time performance will depend on how the compiler optimizes, but also on the distribution of the keys in the array (in particular, the probability of a hit rather than a miss).

I disagree with all comments "against" the second method (even claimed buggy when it is perfectly correct). It is based on a principle that potentially makes it better: there's only one test in the body of the loop.

Having a comparison for equality (Method 1) gives the false feeling that the algorithm will terminate early when the key is found and make the search faster*. But this is not so true, because for half of the keys the full depth of the decision tree is anyway necessary, and this not counter-balanced by the fact that there are two comparisons instead of one.

*In fact, you just spare *one* test on average !

---

Only benchmarking can tell you if one of the methods is faster with particular test cases. My bet is that the distributions of the running times overlap a lot. (Not counting that it is virtually impossible to benchmark such a fast algorithm in a way that is representative of its behavior in real context.)

---

Last comment: the method 2 is a *binary* search, while in fact method 1 is *ternary* !

Comment: If we had a primitive to perform `b=clear_all_bits_but_most_significant(n)`, then the while could be converted into an if, making method 2 even more efficient.

Comment: @aka.nice: modern processors do have conditional move instructions, which don't suffer the heavy cost of conditional branches. It is likely that an optimizer will use them here.

Comment: re. your last comment. For method 1, you could move the _equal_ comparison below the loop to make the two equivalent in that regard,

Comment: It's quibbling over semantics, and perhaps not important but method 2 can be called "ternary" because the array is split into three parts when n is odd: [0, n/2), [n/2, n-1) and [n-1, n). "Split" in the sense that exactly one of these three ranges will be descended into in the next iteration.

Comment: Only one comparison doesn't seem to be correct for the 2nd implementation. First you check k + b < n and then you check array[k + b] <= x. Those are executed about 1.5 times, so 3 tests on average +1 for the loop termination makes 4 tests. The first method only has 3 tests. I would bet on it that it is faster.

Comment: @PaulHankin: you are right, there is a flaw in the Method 2, it is more complicated than need be. There should not be an inner `while` loop, it is possible to work with an `if`.

Comment: If you write method 2 in the "simpler" way you're suggesting, you end up with almost the same code as in method 1 (except for the == comparison). Just representing the range as (start, len) rather than (start, end).

Comment: @PaulHankin: exactly.